# Volume control do not work for bluetooth speaker

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 21.10, bluetooth-speaker

I have recently purchased a new bluetooth speaker and it pairs fine in my ubuntu 21.10. However, the volume control in ubuntu do not seem to work and I instead have to use the volume controls on the speaker.

I have tried a few things like connecting/disconnecting, restarting etc but the problem continues.

Volume controls seems to work fine with an older bluetooth speaker.

I'm at a loss so any ideas welcome

Comment: Install `pavucontrol` and run it. Can you change a volume in it ?

Comment: no, I cannot change  the volume using `pavucontrol`